# Magento 2 get product attribute value without objectManager

Tags: product, product-attribute, object-manager

I load some related products inside a foreach and want to call some attribute values of these individual products.

My current code below works fine with using $objectManager, but that's not the best way to handle this.

How can I get the value of the product attribute, without using the $objectManager ?

Code Helper/Data:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\LinkedProducts\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \MagePal\LinkProduct\Model\Accessory $accessory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $abstractProduct
    ) {
        $this->accessory = $accessory;
        $this->abstractProduct = $abstractProduct;
    }

    public function getLinkedProducts()
    {
    $product = $this->abstractProduct->getProduct();    
    return $this->accessory->getAccessoryProducts($product);
    }

}
```

Code phtml:

```
<?php $linkedproducts = $this->helper('MyModule\LinkedProducts\Helper\Data');
$relatedProducts = $linkedproducts->getLinkedProducts();?>

<?php foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($relatedProduct->getId());
echo $_product->getData('my_attribute_value');
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more function in your helper class to load product info and call same function in PHTML.

Updated code will be like as below:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\LinkedProducts\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function __construct(
    \MagePal\LinkProduct\Model\Accessory $accessory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $abstractProduct,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
) {
    $this->accessory = $accessory;
    $this->abstractProduct = $abstractProduct;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}

public function getLinkedProducts()
{
    $product = $this->abstractProduct->getProduct();    
    return $this->accessory->getAccessoryProducts($product);
}

public function getProductInfo($productId)
{
    $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
    return $_product;
}    

}
```

PHTML Code:

```
<?php 
$linkedproducts = $this->helper('MyModule\LinkedProducts\Helper\Data');
$relatedProducts = $linkedproducts->getLinkedProducts();?>

<?php 
    foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {

        $_product = $linkedproducts->getProductInfo($relatedProduct->getId());
        echo $_product->getData('my_attribute_value');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But it seems that something is wrong in the code. I get a blank page when editing the helper data. Are we missing something?

Comment: By uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); from bootstrap.php file .. you can see error instead of blank page

Comment: Thanks a lot, was something small as adding a `;` after the `return $_product`. I edit your answer, so that we have the correct code! :)

Comment: It seems not working 100% well. The foreach is not working when loading the `echo $_product->getData('my_attribute_value');`. It only loads the value of the first product and displays that value for all other products as well. What are we missing here?

Comment: As addition, when loading `echo $_product->getName();` we do get the unique value of the specific product.  So that works well. But for example `<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product);?>` also displays the value of the first one.

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please check

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works perfect. Only 1 question left, how can I get the sorting of the related products from the backend? So that the foreach is loading the products with the right sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by add new function in your helper and call in phtml.

> **Helper File :**

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\LinkedProducts\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    private $accessory;
    private $abstractProduct;
    private $productFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \MagePal\LinkProduct\Model\Accessory $accessory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $abstractProduct,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->accessory = $accessory;
        $this->abstractProduct = $abstractProduct;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function getLinkedProducts()
    {
        $product = $this->abstractProduct->getProduct();    
        return $this->accessory->getAccessoryProducts($product);
    }

    public function getAttributeInfo($productId = null)
    {
        if($productId){
            $productObj = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
            return $productObj->getData('my_attribute_value');
        }
        return '';
    }

}
```

> **Phtml file :**

```
<?php

$linkedproducts = $this->helper('MyModule\LinkedProducts\Helper\Data');
$relatedProducts = $linkedproducts->getLinkedProducts();

foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
    echo $linkedproducts->getAttributeInfo($relatedProduct->getId());
}
?>
```

Remove generated and clean cache.

Comment: how to call this getAttributeInfo function in another php file?